# Can I use sencha cmd as to minify/compress?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-cmd

We have an ExtJS modern app.  We would like to use cmd to minimize/compress our code into a single .js file - effectively doing what a non Ext app would do with other minifiers like uglifyjs or terser.

I believed we could achieve this with the compile command such as:

```
sencha -sdk ext-7.1.0.46 compile -cl=myclassfolder -inp=ES6 concat outfile.js
```

However, it complains that it can't find the Ext classes with an error like:

```
[ERR] Failed to resolve dependency Ext.data.Model for file myapp.model.mymodel
[ERR] Unknown definition for dependency : Ext.data.Model
```

It seems to be the basic task of extending Ext.data.Model it doesn't like and very much feels like I simply need to reference the extJS class structure correctly for this to work, but can't figure out the command line to make it happen (I somewhat assumed that the sdk reference would fix this).

Is this possible?

Comment: sencha app build (development / production) does that for you. it will create a single file with all dependencies - if invoked with development it will concat and with production it will concat and uglify the file.

Comment: Thanks, but we have a complex app with dynamic class loading (for multi-client configurations, performance and security reasons) where the "all in one" sencha architecture just doesn't work, so are looking for more control over the minification process.  We do have a solution now however, which I will come back this week to add for anyone in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, to help anyone who is facing the same problem and wants to compress/minify their ExtJS but without creating a full sencha app.

The command is fairly simple and the answer is to include the path to your dependent js files in the -cl (or -classpath) argument, then exlude the Ext namespace:

```
sencha -sdk stack/Sencha/ext-7.2.0 compile -cl=ext-modern-all.js,packages/ux/modern/ux.js,myclassfolder -inp=ES6 exclude -namespace Ext and concat outfile.js
```

You can then use terser or your preferred minify tools to minify/mangle the output (or add the compress command to the above to allow cmd to minify also).  It's a reasonable way to build your ExtJS code into several manageable extjs "modules" which can be loaded when needed (or when security allows) rather than the "big bang" approach of cmd.

This will produce a single js file, correctly ordered, the only issue is that it includes the Ext microloader code, which it adds by default.  I have not managed to have the compiler not inlcude the microloader, however you can effectively disable it by defining the microloader yourself between the load of your ext-all.js file and your newly created file by using something like this is another file or inline script tag:

```
Ext.Microloader = {
    run: function(){}
};
```

I know there aren't many folks left using ExtJS, hope this helps someone at some point, at worst case it allows a bit more control of the ExtJS build process.